# Removing T4MVC from my VS2010 solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, t4mvc

I'm very new to VS2010, so this is more a question about using Visual Studio 2010 than T4MVC.

Anyway, I wanted to remove T4MVC from my solution, so I deleted the two files from my root directory.  However, when I rebuild and debug my solution, I still see compilation warnings associated with **T4MVC.tt**.  What step am I missing here?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can, please post the errors you receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you delete the two files from Visual Studio and not from the explorer (maybe that's what you;re doing already?).  This way, it not only deletes t4mvc.tt, but also all the generated files that are under it.

That should be all it takes to remove T4MVC.  If that doesn't do it, can you update your question with more details about the specific warnings you're seeing?  Also, do you see this issue on a brand new project, or only on some more complex project?

Comment: It's a pretty basic project: I'm currently working through the exercises in Chapter 3 of Sanderson's MVC 2 book (http://apress.com/book/view/1430228865).  Complexity is very low.

I think I may have accidentally deleted the files physically from my PC before removing the references from Visual Studio.  But humor me for a second: where should I be looking in VS2010 for my solution's references?  As I said before, I'm pretty new to... well, everything.  So I may not be looking in the right place.

Comment: If you are referring to assembly references, you can find them by expanding the 'References' node under your project (in the Solution Explorer).

Comment: Maybe VS2010 is still compiling the old .generated.cs files T4MVC makes. If you deleted the .tt file outside VS2010 that could be the problem after you start updating the controllers. I think the most clean way to remove T4MVC is to delete it from within VS2010. Or if you've used NuGet to get T4MVC just uninstall the package.